# How to manipulate the date format in reminders

Tags: windows-phone-7

The date in reminder is US format ( mm/dd/yyyy) By default I guess. How to manipulate the collection of reminders and format the date to british format  so that the listBox will show the reminders as below:

Begin Date ( in British Format or non-US format) 
Content

```
MyReminders = ScheduledActionService.GetActions()
                .Where(a => a.BeginTime.Date == Today);

 foreach (Reminder r in MyReminders)
{
 // How to change the date format to British  in each of the reminder and display 
    in the listBox?

}

   ReminderListBox.ItemsSource = MyReminders;


In the list Box :



<ListBox Name="ReminderListBox" Margin="1,116,-2,4" >
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Background="Transparent" Margin="0,0,0,30">   

         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >                                       

         <TextBlock Text="begin "/>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding BeginTime}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
          </StackPanel>

               </Grid>
         </DataTemplate/>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate/>
 </ListBox />
```

problems : I dont want to set the date format in the listbox. I want to dynamically detect the locale and display the date Format base on the detected locale Ex Non-US format for Jpn, Kor, China

Answer (score 1):

What does your listbox template look like? You should be able to make it pick the "right" date format for the culture using a format specifier of "d" (for short date) or "D" (for long date) ... and I'd expect you to be able to do that from XAML rather than changing anything else.

Note that the `DateTime` itself doesn't *have* a format - so it's not like you could set that value to be "in" UK format.

EDIT: I *think* you want:

```
{Binding BeginTime, StringFormat=d}
```

or if you want to *force* a specific format (which I don't recommend)

```
{Binding BeginTime, StringFormat=dd/MM/yyyy}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just updated my question. What I want is to detect the phone's locale, then display the date format base on it. So, How to I get the date format. Thanks

Comment: yes. This is what I wanted. The question is (1) If the phone locale is Taiwan, how this {Binding BeginTime,StringFormat=d} inside the ListBox DataTemplate is going to show? will it show DD/MM/YYYY ?? (2) How to I pass this stringFormat dynamically to the ListBox DataTemplate? Thanks

Comment: @MilkBottle: 1) I don't know - I suggest you try :) 2) I'm not sure whether you can change that dynamically easily enough... beyond my expertise, to be honest. But you shouldn't *need* to. It should "do the right thing".

Comment: Did anyone tried this in Phone Emulator? I'm using StringFormat=d but the date format is still mm/dd/yyyy regardless regional settings (+ emulator internal reboot) I set. I'm unable to test on a real phone to see whether this is just an emulator issue.

Comment: @AntoninJelinek: Don't forget there are two sets of regional settings on the phone, IIRC. I can't remember which is responsible for what, offhand...